Creating DUnit test case for COM DLL application
I'm using Delphi 10.2 for developing application and I have COM object application where the COM is initialized in the initialization section and I need to create the Comobject class from DUnit application and then, I have access the Invoke method after creation and then, included the unit file in the DUNIT application with the all reference files and  getting the error - "Error Loading type DLL".
And tried to create CreateCOMObject and also createOLEObject for the COM instance. But got access violation error. How can I create COM class and access the invoke method from DUnit Delphi application? Kinldy share your comments

Is it DUnit or DUnitX?

I'm using DUnitx

"I have COM object application where the COM is initialized in the initialization section" - are you creating a in-proc DLL or an out-of-proc EXE for your COM object? Either way, COM should not be initialized in a unit initialization section, especially for a DLL. In any case, the ComObj unit handles COM initialization for you.

I have tried in both ways - in intialization and also create part of the Test class and got the same errors and I have included win.comsvr unit in the DUnit test project and tried to register the application and got the run time error message
